# In ZF2 how do you display an image in a view

Tags: image, view, controller, zend-framework2

I can insert an image into a ZF2 view by simply entering an HTML tag in the PHTML file:

```
<img src='/images/myimage.jpg' class='img-class' width='250' alt='a pretty picture'/>
```

Is this the proper way to do it?  Is there a proper way?

Other posts refer to calling up images through the controller.  What is the benefit of doing that?

Comment: Sometimes you have use-cases where you want to re-render a picture, let's say a user uploads 1000x1000px and you add functionality to crop the image to 100x200px plus adding a watermark. This resize stuff can be done within a controller action on the fly and the image stream could be returned. But generally, as @Tim Fountain told you, this is the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is the correct way. It's hard to say what the other posts you mention are referring to without specific examples.